# Is this proof for almost surely convergent valid?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

If I want to show that a sequence of random variables $X_n$ has the property $P(X_n\rightarrow 0)=1$, is that enough to show $\forall\epsilon>0,P(|X_n|\ge\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$? 
I think the second one looks like a sense of "convergent by measure". Maybe it is not enough. So I want to know is that valid or is there a counter example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not it is not. The second property is called "convergence in probability". Almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability but the converse is false.

The usual example if to take the characteristic functions $X_{m,n}=\mathbf{1}_{\left[\frac{m-1}{n},\frac{m}{n}\right]}$ for $1 \leq m \leq n$ and sort these variables in the order $\ldots,X_{1,n},\ldots,X_{n,n},X_{1,n+1},\ldots$ That is to say, you cut $[0,1]$ in smaller and smaller subintervals. Then $\mathbf{P}(|X_{m,n}| > \varepsilon) = \dfrac{1}{n}$ so the sequence converges in probability towards $0$. But for every point $x$ of $[0,1]$, there are infinitely many $(m,n)$ such that $X_{m,n}(x)=1$.